# Remove $.get from array of $.gets on "done"

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

My problem is that I need to detect when a `$.get` is complete, then remove itself from the global `var ajaxGets` and detect when the `ajaxGets` variable is empty so I can hide my loading-image.

The page uses several ajax gets. a few runs in the background independent of user input, and the rest are specific gets based on input.

So while I have an `$.get` running in a `setTimeout` loop doing its own thing, there's several others than are chained like below, that i need to keep track of.

```
//psudo
$.get(".....", success(){
    $.get("...", success() {
        $.get("...")...
    }
}
```

I chain them like this in order to get data in a particular order async.

The user selects a few checkboxes and clicks "update" and `$.get`s start.

If the user clicks "update" while there's `$.gets` in progress, I figured that I could prevent the chains of `$.gets` by doing something like this

```
var ajaxGets = []

var req1 = $.get(".....", success(){
    var req2 = $.get("...", success() {
        var req3 = $.get("...", success(){

        })
        ajaxGets.push(req3)
    })
    ajaxGets.push(req2)
})
ajaxGets.push(req1)
```

and then inside my `click` for the update button I'll just abort all the `$.gets` and reset the global variable that contains them, before starting the new query of `$.get`s

```
    for (var g in ajaxGets) {
        ajaxGets[g].abort();
    }

    ajaxGets = [];
```

This works well. No problem.

But how do I remove a particular `$.get` from an array of `var ajaxGets` when the `$.get` is done, so I then can find out if the array is empty (all the ajax gets in the array either failed or succeded)?

please ask if anything is unclear

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It sure sounds like you'd want to promisify all this, though.

Comment: @NachoDawg _"But how do I remove a particular $.get from an array of var ajaxGets when the $.get is done"_ Can remove an item from an array using `Array.prototype.splice()`

Comment: @guest271314 but how do I find that "get" in the array in order to splice it off?

Comment: @NachoDawg Try using `$.grep()` or `Array.prototype.filter()` to filter jQuery promise object returned by `$.get()` where `state` of promise object is not `"pending"` , `.splice()` non-pending promise objects from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to determine when all your requests are complete.

```
var ajaxGets = [...]; //your array of get requests 
$.when.apply($, ajaxGets).then(function() {
    alert('all gets complete!');
});
```

Comment: This does answer my question on how to detect when an array of gets are done. I just made a function called "ajaxCompleteHandler()" and then call it at the end of my "update" function right after the ajax gets are triggered to start, Thank you.